# Margin-top value of clear: left

Tags: html, css, margin

So, I have this code for emulating a table, and I'd just like to know if the margin-top for paragraphs that are cleared is always 16 ~ 17 px. Yes, I know I could just use `<table>` for tables and whatnot, but the point is to not use the table element.
If you're confused, just edit and run this code in your browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title></title>
<style type = 'text/css'>

body {margin: 0px; font-family: "Times New Roman";}

#board {position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 50px; 
height: 481px; width: 481px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color: black; }

div.row > p:first-child { clear: left; } 

#board > div.row:first-child { margin-top: -16px;} 
#msg p { margin-top: -17px; }
div.row {margin-left: 1px; }

p { width: 31px; height: 31px; padding: 0px; border: 1px #DFDEDC solid; 
float: left; margin-left: -1px; color: black; text-align: right; }

</style></head>
<body>
<div id = 'board'>
<div class = 'row'><p></p> // 15 paragraphs </div>

<div id = 'msg'>
<div class = "row"><p></p> ... </div>
<div class = "row"><p></p> ... </div>
<div class = "row"><p></p> ... </div>
<div class = "row"><p></p> ... </div>
<div class = "row"><p></p> ... </div>
<div class = "row"><p></p> ... </div> // 15 rows, etc
</div> // end msg
</div> // end board
</body>
</html>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Y9PD/)

I guess what I'm really trying to say is: do all browsers 'clear' by the same amount, so to speak, or do different browsers 'clear' elements by different amounts? Chrome seems to clear by 16 or 17px, and so does Firefox and IE. But is this truly consistent across browsers? Thanks

Comment: This has nothing to do with `float` or `clear`. What your are seeing is the browsers' default margin on `<p>` elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it can depend on the browser.

Better use

```
#board p { margin: 0px; }
```

to remove margins.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Y9PD/1/)

---

To make it look like exactly like your code, I have done a few changes:

```
body{/*...*/} #board{/*...*/}
#board .row {
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#board p { 
    width: 31px;
    height: 31px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 1px #DFDEDC solid; 
    float: left; 
    margin: 0px; margin-right: -1px;
    color: black; 
    text-align: right;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Y9PD/2/)

Comment: Oh nice. That's great!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why would you want to emulate a table. But first, if I understand the question correctly, you want to know what are the default margin values of the tag `<p>` for all the browsers or if they are different so and so. Well that has nothing to do with the table or your attempt to emulate one. The answer is yes, there are differences depending on the browser and the version, which is why you need to manually set the margin with CSS so that all browsers will then have to "clear" the same amout.

Cheers.

---

Also a `<p>` tag may have default `padding` so you need to specify that as well.

Comment: I am using jqueryui to programmatically position any div in the center of any element on the board. Firefox does not correctly position these divs when using tables. So, I am using paragraphs. Secondly, while tables might be cleaner in terms of usability, this format uses less characters, and therefore uses less bandwidth and money. This only a trial implementation of the board, because I will be creating the board programmatically as well when I am finished, but I first needed to make sure everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

All browsers have different default settings for how they render html elements. It's common practice to use a normalize css file to make sure all browsers display everything the same. You can try to write one yourself, but why reinvent the wheel?

http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Comment: Seems a bit overkill. Just set the margin and padding style to 0 for each element, including the body and html and everything should work fine. Am I wrong? In fact, there's no css even needed; I can do this easily with a for statement and some jquery code.

Comment: Assuming you want to continue development on the website, you are likely to run into reset issues in the future as you continue to add html elements. Why bring jQuery into the mix when simple css works?

Comment: Because I am using jquery anyway to programmatically position every element on the webpage, as everything is absolutely positioned. I forgot to mention that part. So there isn't too much leeway for the browsers. But for anything that isn't absolutely positioned, I'll be sure to look into CSS libraries, if necessary.

Comment: Yeah, you should have a fallback for noscript. If someone has their javascript disabled the site should still be functional.

Comment: I'm creating a live gaming website. Users without javascript enabled aren't exactly going to be my best customers. Besides, there would be a noscript in the login part of the website that would forward them to  a special webpage telling them that JavaScript must be enabled. And no, you can't create a live gaming website without JavaScript, unless you want to use Flash or something. And Flash can be disabled too. Use both? Sure, when I've got the first working.